# Access React types in props interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a functional component like so:

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';

import {
  ButtonStyled,
  LinkStyled,
  Text,
} from './index.style';


export interface Props {
  buttonType?: string;
  handleClick?: () => void;
  href?: string;
  invertColors?: boolean;
  isDisabled?: boolean;
  isLoading?: boolean;
  text: string;
  variant?: 'dark' | 'light';
}

const defaultProps = {
  buttonType: 'button',
  handleClick: null,
  href: null,
  invertColors: false,
  isDisabled: false,
  isLoading: false,
  variant: 'dark',
};


const Button = ({
  buttonType,
  handleClick,
  href,
  isDisabled,
  isLoading,
  text,
  variant,
}: Props) => {
  if (href) {
    return (
      <LinkStyled
        href={href}
        isDisabled={isDisabled}
        isLoading={isLoading}
        variant={variant}
      >
        <Text isLoading={isLoading}>
          {text}
        </Text>
      </LinkStyled>
    );
  }

  return (
    <ButtonStyled
      disabled={isDisabled}
      isDisabled={isDisabled}
      isLoading={isLoading}
      onClick={handleClick}
      type={buttonType}
      variant={variant}
    >
      <Text isLoading={isLoading}>
        {text}
      </Text>
    </ButtonStyled>
  );
};


Button.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default memo(Button);
```

There is a single Typescript error in this file and it's to do with the line `type={buttonType}`. The error is:

```
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type '"button" | "reset" | "submit" | undefined'.
```

I understand this error. React types have declared the 'type' attribute must be either 'button', 'reset', 'submit' or 'undefined' but I have set my props to be either string or undefined.

My question is, how do I assign the options from React to my props to avoid duplication by typing out all the options manually?

EDIT: The full error here:

```
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type '"button" | "reset" | "submit" | undefined'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"button" | "reset" | "submit" | undefined'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1849, 9): The expected type comes from property 'type' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement>, "form" | "style" | "title" | "className" | "color" | ... 259 more ... | "value"> & { ...; } & ButtonStyledProps, "isDisabled" | ... 267 more ... | "value"> & Partial<...>, "isDisabled" | ... 267 more ....'
```

The type in question from @types/react looks like this:

```
interface ButtonHTMLAttributes<T> extends HTMLAttributes<T> {
  autoFocus?: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
  form?: string;
  formAction?: string;
  formEncType?: string;
  formMethod?: string;
  formNoValidate?: boolean;
  formTarget?: string;
  name?: string;
  type?: 'submit' | 'reset' | 'button';
  value?: string | string[] | number;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can use also [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#partial-readonly-record-and-pick) e.g. `type ButtonType = Pick<ButtonHTMLAttributes<any>, 'type'>;`

Comment: @MoshFeu `Pick` could probably be used so extract a object type that only contains `type`, here the OP needs to use the type in the type of `buttonType`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Isn't going to work? https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD8QT.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a type query to get access to the type of `type`:

```
type ButtonType = JSX.IntrinsicElements['button']['type']
```

Using this type (or directly the type query) as the type for `buttonType` should solve your issue:

```
export interface Props {
  buttonType?: ButtonType; // or directly JSX.IntrinsicElements['button']['type']
  handleClick?: () => void;
  href?: string;
  invertColors?: boolean;
  isDisabled?: boolean;
  isLoading?: boolean;
  text: string;
  variant?: 'dark' | 'light';
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Do you know if this sort of thing is documented anywhere and where I would find that?

Comment: @Coop this is the section on index types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types The application of them to this case comes strictly from me, but it is something I would expect to be future proof.